# Defuzzification process of fuzzy sets in RDBMS

Tags: artificial-intelligence, rdbms, paradox, fuzzy-logic

I have a table that stores all values..eg x1, x2, x3 which determines fuzzy sets. Degree of membership is assigned to each using mathematical functions for Low, Med, High.

My rule 1 states that if x1 is high AND x2 is medium then probability of output is z.
I then take min{x1,x2} to evaluate the rule.  Rule 2 states that if x2 is high OR x3 is medium then output is max{x2,x3}.

Now to defuzzify I take aggregation of rule consequences to find out the output of the 2 rules.  I have all degrees of membership defined (0 to 1) for x1 x2 x3 for each rule.

How do I defuzzify?

Comment: I don't think you've given us enough information yet...can explain what how the rules are stored?  In a table?  If so, what's the schema?  If not, in what form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, first of all, are you using a probabilistic logic or a fuzzy logic.  While similar, they're not identical.  If you're really modeling probabilities here, then you need to look into this via Bayes Theorem as a conditional probability.

If these are really *fuzzy* truth values, then you need to have a model of set-membership, which we need to know.

Comment: The sets are fuzzy and Bayesian reasoning won't be applied..  
Fuzzy output is defined as the degree of membership to which they belong[not the probability as output].I forgot that the consequent of the rule could have multiple parts.  This was the missing link!
Now ok!

The problem is now solved -

Comment: Yay!  Haven't done fuzzy systems in a long time, fun to think back to them.